# Can a vertex group be excluded from the effects of a modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I am primarily looking at the Subdivision modifier for this. The hope is to streamline a workflow by merging a few meshes before applying their modifiers. This would avoid the need for merging them after the modifier is applied. And that merge step needs to be remembered and repeated every single time the pre-modified (unsubdivided) mesh needs an edit.

It could save a lot of time in the long run to simply merge them now, and have a portion of the mesh be specifically excluded from subdividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, most modifiers can be modulated by a vertex group, and for most modifiers, that vertex group can be inverted:

[image]

Here, I've specified a vertex group in my modifier, and then I've clicked the button to the right of that group's name in my modifier, telling Blender that I want it to be read inverted-- excluding the effects of the Displace modifier from vertex group "Group".

A subdivision modifier cannot be given a vertex group.  Part of the reason for that is that it's ambiguous: should we create a new vertex between one vertex that should be subdivided and one that shouldn't?  Part of it is because we would create unattractive ngons by only subdividing some parts of a mesh.

However, when you're talking about joining various bits into a single object, you're probably talking about multiple, discontinuous meshes.  We can use a fairly simple geometry nodes modifier to subdivide some of these meshes but not others:

[image]

Here, the two monkeys are joined into a single object, but one is assigned to Group and one isn't.  The GN modifier subdivides only the mesh that is not assigned to Group, by separating the geometry by vertex group, doing some operations, and then rejoining.

However, this would not work well for marking parts of the same, continuous mesh for different levels of subdivision:

[image]

The simple technique demonstrated loses connecting faces; if we were to find a way around that, we'd need to find a way to reconnect the vertices to prevent gaps and to preserve continuous normals.  It is possible to *patch* a subdivided mesh to an un-subdivided mesh, by transferring position to C-C subdivided patch edges from simply subdivided patch edges, and then copying normals from a base; it's possible, with GN, to do all of that inside of a single object.  But I'm not sure if that is necessary for what you want to achieve, and don't want to go off on what would be a lengthy tangent if it's not.

Answer (score 3):

There's no vertex group in the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, but there's the *Edge Crease* tool (mesh on the left): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Edge Crease* and the crease value is available in the *N panel > Item > Transform > Edges Data > Mean Crease*. But the best would be to sharpen your edges with support edges, here on the right the edges are bevelled (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: I still wish we had 3DS's _Editable Mesh_, though...

Comment: does it allow to subdivide the vertex groups only?